# Securing ports on Linux with multi-factor authentication

Tags: linux, security

I have dedicated Ubuntu server in the Internet so I want to:

1. Connect to my server via HTTP(s)
2. Input password and MFA token (i.e. Google Authenticator token)
3. If both are correct, server executes iptables rule that temporary opens some ports to IP i've authenticated from

What is the best/easiest way to implement that?

Why not libpam-google-authenticator + ssh:

- I do not want to expose ssh port by default. I use key-based auth but nevertheless.
- I want to run automation scripts from my machine w/o entering MFA token every time
- I want to work from Windows using Cygwin ssh

Comment: Can you elaborate on why an exposed HTTPS server is ok but ssh is not?

Comment: @AlexHolst because breaching of specialized HTTPS server means little exposure while breaching of sshd which runs as root and used to gain access to host...

Comment: You must run very different httpd and sshd servers than the rest of the world. Sorry I can't be of much assistance.